# What consequences does "references in call_user_func_array are deprectated" have on form api?

Tags: forms

The [documentation on call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) has a note, part of it quoted below

> Before PHP 5.4, referenced variables in param_arr are passed to the function by reference, regardless of whether the function expects the respective parameter to be passed by reference. This form of call-time pass by reference does not emit a deprecation notice, but it is nonetheless deprecated, and has been removed in PHP 5.4.

The function [drupal_retrieve_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form/7) uses call_user_func_array in building the form, and has this comment shortly before the call:

> We need to pass $form_state by reference in order for forms to modify it,
>   since call_user_func_array() requires that referenced variables are passed
>   explicitly.

While I haven't hit any serious issues [running PHP 5.4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27754/php-5-4-and-drupal-7/28565), it sounds to me like anything that builds a form and then relies on getting back a modified form_state will break on 5.4. I may not entirely understand what's happening here however.

**What are the consequences for Form API of this PHP 5.4 change?**

Comment: The sentence after that says, "Passing by value when the function expects a parameter by reference results in a warning and having `call_user_func()` return `FALSE`." I would take it means you cannot pass as reference a value the function expect not passed as reference, such as in the case the function is defined as `my_module_form_builder($form, $form_state)`.

Comment: Yes, now that you point it out, and I read it again, that does seem reasonable.

Comment: What I find confusing is the other sentence: "Furthermore, this does not apply to internal functions, for which the function signature is honored." It makes the think the function signature us not honored for user functions. I wish somebody answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

No expert, but here's my punt:

> Before PHP 5.4, referenced variables in param_arr are passed to the function by reference, regardless of whether the function expects the respective parameter to be passed by reference. This form of call-time pass by reference ... has been removed in PHP 5.4

means

```
function myfunction($a, $b) {
  $a++;
  $b++;
  print "myfunction($a, $b)\n";
}

$apples = 10;
$bananas = 20;

// PHP < 5.4: $b is passed by reference, not honouring the function signature
call_user_func_array('myfunction', array($apples, &$bananas));
print("apples: $apples, bananas: $bananas\n");
// PHP < 5.4: $apples = 10, $bananas = 21
// PHP >= 5.4: $apples = 10, $bananas = 20
```

and

> Furthermore, this does not apply to internal functions, for which the function signature is honored.

presumably means (though it seems a bit unnecessary?):

```
$angle = 1.5;

// Despite passing by reference, there's no chance of $angle changing as the
// function signature's honored for internal functions.
$res = call_user_func('sin', array(&$angle));
```

Letharion wrote:

> it sounds to me like anything that builds a form and then relies on getting back a modified form_state will break on 5.4

It seems to me like this should be fine, in this case at least: we're passing
a reference exactly where it's expected by the function signature (I presume this is still the right way to pass by reference where that matches the signature). However if I *am* right, then any modules with typos in their form hooks like this `function MYMODULE_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id)` will work exactly as expected under PHP < 5.4, but 'suddenly' mess up on 5.4.

@Letharion: in another answer you mention you have 5.4 running: I would've thought something would've exploded by now if it wasn't passing `$form_state` by reference? But IIUC if the following works as expected in 5.4, then the code you reference should be ok:

```
function myfunction(&$a) {
  $a++;
  print "myfunction($a)\n";
}

$a = 10;

call_user_func_array('myfunction', array(&$a));
print "a: $a\n";
// We expect a to be 11 the second time for all versions of PHP.
```

My 2 pennies